# Unable to bypass CORS in any browser Dec 2017

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, cors, firefox-addon

we are developing web app using React.js consuming java rest API.
we have not enabled the CORS on the server side due to some internal issues.
Now we want to bypass the CORS for testing purpose in our local. Previously I used to do the same using chrome/firefox extensions, but now all of them becomes absolute.

**Error:**

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/ValueStat/secure/login. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

Is there any other option to test ???

Answer (score 1):

due to browser security policy this issue is coming, i am suggestion following solutions please try  it one by one. best of luck!

- (1 solution ) if you server is support JSONP so please use it for refrance in detail please visit this link  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp
- (2 solution )  you need to run site and service both are in same domain.
- (3 solution ) [image: see attachted image]

Comment: Do not confuse JSON and JSONP